# How to make random string of numbers and letters with a length of 5?

Tags: c#, string, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this a good way to generate a string of random characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976646/is-this-a-good-way-to-generate-a-string-of-random-characters)
>   [How can I generate random 8 character, alphanumeric strings in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-8-character-alphanumeric-strings-in-c)

This is the code that I have so far.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rand1 = RandomString(5);
        string rand2 = RandomString(5);
        string rand3 = RandomString(5);
        string rand4 = RandomString(5);
        string rand5 = RandomString(5);
        textBox1.Text = rand1 + "-" + rand2 + "-" + rand3 + "-" + rand4 + "-" + rand5;

    }
    private static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    private string RandomString(int Size)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
            builder.Append(ch);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

BUT it just creates a random string of 5 chars.
I want it to create a string of 5 chars and integers.
How would I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I strongly recommend http://stackoverflow.com/a/1344255/445517 over other answers, if the number needs high entropy or must be secure.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: If the output *really* needs to be secure then the answer you've linked to is *not* suitable. It uses mod to index into the `chars` array so it'll exhibit bias unless `chars.Length` happens to be a divisor of 256. (It also has the bug that you call out in your comment there.)

Comment: @LukeH For typical character sets (say up to 64 chars) the bias will be relatively small, and thus probably isn't a risk in practice. I'm too lazy to write a good solution that doesn't depend on my randomgen library.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use an input array to draw your values from:

```
private static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var c = pool[random.Next(0, pool.Length)];
        builder.Append(c);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Or the (inevitable) Linq solution:

```
private static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, length)
        .Select(x => pool[random.Next(0, pool.Length)]);
    return new string(chars.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem or not, but maybe it's worth pointing out that your code will pick letters more often than digits.

Comment: +1, Exactly! I've no idea where the OP's `Convert.ToChar`-`Convert.ToInt32`-`Math.Floor`-`NextDouble` monstrosity came from originally, but it turns up in loads of SO questions (and answers, unfortunately).

Comment: Not sure why this works for everyone else but not me.
When i call the RandomString method, I get identical digits, 16 of them to be precise. From experience, calling Random.Next within a loop, or via Lambda expression/loops - calls the Random.Next so rapidly, that it gets the same seed each time.
For a truly random seed, you should feed in

Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()  into the constructor for your Random();

Comment: You should not initialize your `Random` instance more than once - definitely do NOT do it as part of the loop

Comment: it's not compiling. check

Comment: @Adrian Hey - looks like someone edited the answer and put in an error - I updated. Keep in mind that this needs the static `Random` instance `random` defined that OP added in his question

Comment: @BrokenGlass yes, I check the code and change it but forget to see it in history to update it. No worry, it's working now.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta: no, it's still now working. It's complaining about the "random" variable !!!!

Comment: @HoangMinh check the OP, it's there in source.

Answer (score 24):

Copying from jon skeet's answer...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/976674/67824

```
Random rand = new Random();

public const string Alphabet = 
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

public string GenerateString(int size)
{
    char[] chars = new char[size];
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = Alphabet[rand.Next(Alphabet.Length)];
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: Instead of copying his answer, vote to close this question as a duplicate and provide a link to the previous incarnation.

Comment: I said I copied *from* his answer, not his answer as is. Judging from the OPS's question, I believe I've changed it enough to be helpful to him.

Comment: +1 This method is about twice as fast as the marked answer. For 10m results, @BrokenGlass=0.4148740 - @OhadSchneider=0.02963571

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
```

by

```
string chars="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ch=chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
```

---

Note that your code doesn't create unpredictable random strings. In particular there are only 2 billion possible results, and if your computer gets restarted often, some of them are much more likely than others.

If you want unpredictable random strings, you should use [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx). You can fine an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344255/445517 , you just need to add the hyphens.